# 1 Better exposed Filters for 2 views blocks

Tags: views

I would like to make a page with 2 Views blocks. The views show the same content type, but in a different format.

Block A contains an OpenLayers map.

Block B contains a listing result.

I want to filter both Views based on taxonomy, but with one exposed filter block.

I've made one Better Exposed Filter for block A, but I don't know how to control both blocks with one exposed filter.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

My solution is just to add a hook `mymodule_form_alter`.

Comment: Can you give a brief overview of what you did with the form alter?

Comment: -1 your accepted answer does not state the *code* that you wrote for `mymodule_form_alter`, only that you used this hook - this is not enough to for an answer to solve the problem. But +1 for your original question (other folks will want to do this) and +1 on MPD's comment asking for the same.

Answer (score 9):

You want to create an attachment view display and add it to your main display. For example, if you currently have the OpenMaps display working, create a listing display as an attachment and attach it to the OpenMaps display. Make sure you set "Inherit exposed filters" to "yes" to ensure both displays are using the same set of filters.
In views 3 you can find this settings in the Attachment display settings: [image: screenshot of attachment settings]

Comment: I have no "Inherit exposed filters" option, only "Inherit contextual filters" one

Comment: You saved me from my misery. The best part is that it's been 3 years since you wrote this! Can't thank you enough.